# RSpec basics: bin/rspec --format doc

Tags: ruby, rspec, windows-7

I've installed RSpec on a win7 lappy and am following along the http://rspec.info/ homepage tutorial to make sure everything works. If I am reading their demo correctly `bin/rspec --format doc` should run the specification test file.

[image]

Instead, I get a system prompt for a text editor... ? I am confused.

[image]

Any explanation of what is going on or guidance about how to get my RSPEC configuration working in accordance to the makers homepage would be great.

FWIW Ruby 2.2.5p319, Bundler version 1.13.1 and gem -v tells me 2.6.7 (originally I had 2.4 but that is broken on windows, so I upgraded according to http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/) Also, I have basic RSpec functionality and have completed the tutorial here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/rspec/rspec_writing_specs.htm

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming. It is a basic Windows user 101 "How do I install software" question. On Windows, the program to use to process a file is determined by the file name (or file extension). `rspec` doesn't have a file extension, and presumably you didn't register the file name. You have to register the file name `rspec` to be processed by `ruby.exe`.

Comment: The dialog you are getting is *exactly* the dialog you get when you tell Windows to open a file, and Windows doesn't know what to do with the file because the file extension or file name isn't registered as a file type and/or the file type isn't associated with a program to process that file type. So, either the file name `rspec` isn't registered as a Ruby file, or Ruby files aren't associated with `ruby.exe`. Did you try associating `rspec` with `ruby.exe`? What happened?

Comment: The documentation you are reading is obviously for Unix, not Windows. The fact that it uses `/` as a path component separator instead of `\` is a dead giveaway. In Unix, the program to use to process a file is indicated within the file itself, and independent of the file extension or file name, therefore, there is never a need for such association.

Comment: @JörgWMittag apologies if this is off-topic, but the solution was simply to explicitly call the commands with ruby. `ruby bin/rspec --format doc` successfully runs the test. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I figured out what I need to do... I just need to explicitly call ruby:

```
ruby bin/rspec --format doc
```

...and the test gets run - YaY!

Per @JörgWMittag, I confirmed my Environment Variable Path to make sure ruby.exe was in there (C:\Ruby22\bin;).

Then looking at my Program Defaults, I thought that maybe I could tell win7 to associate any file named "rspec" with ruby.exe per https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/18539/windows-7-change-default-programs ...but I couldn't actually add file type "extensions" or "protocols" - I could only change the association of existing ones, but .rb and .rbw were in there... Maybe there is a way to do this manually, but I am not a windows expert.

Thinking on all this it occurred to me that I just needed to explicitly tell ruby to ingest the command... Heh.

I apologize if this is off-topic.

Comment: I suppose I could browse to ruby.exe from the "Choose the program you want" dialogue box and select ruby.exe as the default to always open "rspec" but I am not certain if this would set ruby.exe to open any file without an extension, or just ones named "rspec"... something for a later day